# Notification to user from admin

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin, django-1.9

I am new in Django and don`t know the best way to realise next functionality in my project.

In my django project I have users with different roles. One of them is admin who can create project. I mean that I have **model with fields (project_name, project_managers)** which filled by admin. The managers of the project are users of the system, admin can choice some of them. After all how to show them  **notification in real time** that they was managers of the current project. Is it makes by websockets or Jquery or something else. I need some ideas how to realise that with detail explanation if it possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [post_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) to implement your notification functionality. This signal will be called once the model object is saved.